# Prevent overlapping UIScrollView from scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` where one of the elements, when touched, pops up another `UIScrollView`, of the same size (full screen) as the underlying view. I want this top scrollView, when shown, to be the only element responding to touches, but as it is, if the top scrollView runs out of content, the underlying scrollView picks up the touches and scrolls its content. How can I force the responder chain to stop at the top `UIScrollView` without putting it in a separate `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting scrollEnabled to NO on the base scroll view when the "top" scroll view is shown, and re-enable it when you want control to return.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the kind of stuff that makes me think, how did I not think of it?